# What can be done if socket creation fails in a service?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, error-handling

I am writing a linux service which will communicate using sockets to client.

This service will be started at the boottime and will run forever till the device is alive.
In this case, at the server, if socket creation fails, how can I handle this error?

Comment: "*... socket creation fails, ...*" fails because of what?

Answer (score 2):

There's not much you can do:

- If the listening socket can't be created, print an error message and exit, hoping someone sees it. There's not much a server can do if it can't listen on some sort of socket
- If a new socket can't be created (using `accept`) log a warning message and hope someone sees it, but don't exit. The error condition (too many open descriptors, not enough memory etc) might be temporary

Comment: And always communicate `errno` perhaps thru `strerror` or `perror` to the sysadmin